# view online user after login on web chat application

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, chat

I've create a chat web apps using php and ajax. I want to ask how store user attribute after login? in this case for view user online or offline. I suggested store user to database using query "INSERT INTO userOnline ...." after login but I want find the best way for this case. Any have good solution? Thanks before.

Comment: You would need to provide more details for anyone to provide an informed suggestion. Eg are you using a interval check or long poll?

Comment: I use interval check, it's refersh <div> each 1 second. what is the different Interval and Long Polling? which one the best way? thanks

Comment: A “long polling” approach is where requests sleep on the server until a new data or changes are found, or until the timeout occurs (or approaches)
A “heartbeat” approach is where regular requests are made to check for new data or changes, eg every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You should send an ajax request in an interval and record the time of the last request in the Database.Use this time to say whether user is online or not.
You may use

```
$record=time();
```

to record the time of request and may use `if ((time()-$record)>interval)`to check whether online or offline
if user is online the if statement would be false